# Async delegate for a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

When using a thread, is it logical to use an async delegate? For example assume that we have a WCF SOAP service and we have a client desktop application that consumes the WCF services. In this application we require to have both Synchronous and Asynchronous mechanisms so sometimes we need to use threads and sometimes async tasks. Now assuming that we need to consume the WCF service in a thread, so we can write the thread in two forms of:

```
Thread Worker = new Thread (()=>{
    WCFServerClient client = new WCFServiceClient();
    var GetData = client.GetData(new GetDataRequest());
});

Thread Worker = new Thread (async ()=>{
    WCFServerClient client = new WCFServiceClient();
    var GetData = await client.GetDataAsync(new GetDataRequest());
});
```

Which one is more logical? I mean does it make sense at all to go for the second option. Asking this because the first also does not affect the responsiveness in the application.

Comment: The best solution is to use `Task` instead of `Thread`: `Task worker = Task.Run(async () => ...);`

Comment: @StephenCleary: Why Stephan, in terms of what the Task is better. If you don;t mind please explain. (I got greed for information)

Comment: It's easier to retrieve results and exceptions. Full description [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thank you very much Stephan, I have another question in here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788395/establishing-proxy-tunnel" about Sockets, in your blog I also found the TCP/IP FAQ section, I think you might be able to help me on that question as well and I really appreciate if you do.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about proxy tunnels.

Comment: @StephenCleary I learned from your blog Task.Run should only use for CPU bound task, if we use `Task.Run(async () => await client.GetDataAsync(new GetDataRequest()) })` here, the async function is not a CPU bounded. And I have another question, when should we use `Task.Run(async () => await FuncAsync() })`? Wrap an async function inside a Task looks a little odd to me.

Comment: @codewarrior: The question stated "assuming that we need to consume the WCF service in a thread" - i.e., there is some external reason why they can't use the proper asynchronous approach. E.g., some shops use a shared interface between server/client for WCF, and it's awkward to switch sync/async signatures in that case. I assume they've weighed the pro of shared interface against the con of burning an extra thread, and decided to stick with the shared interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your examples are running independently of the UI thread, which is why neither example would affect responsiveness.

So what is the difference in behavior?

In your second example, the thread that you have created will terminate before `GetData` has completed. When `GetData` has completed, your code will continue on a different thread, taken from the thread pool.

Both are 'logical', but whether it is better or not depends upon your usage requirements.

Terminating your thread and then utilising the thread pool means that your thread count might stay lower, so your application will be using less resources.

However, if your application is already using the maximum number of thread pool threads, then there may be a wait to process the returned data as you are waiting for a thread pool thread to become available.

This would only matter in the case where scalability is the issue and you are using the maximum amount of machine resources you can. In the majority of cases, this would be making no discernable difference at all.

Comment: So the second option is more CPU friendly if I'm not mistaken, is that right?

Comment: @James - I suspect not. The second option is more resource friendly, but not more CPU friendly. It would take CPU cycles to bundle everything up and then dispatch it all to a pooled  thread later. But we're talking tiny amounts.